# db.model_from_protobuf() equivalents outside of AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, protocol-buffers, google-compute-engine

In Google AppEngine(GAE) environment, I can do following to convert a Protobuf bytestring back to a Datastore model:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

byte_str = ....
model = db.model_from_protobuf(byte_str.decode("base64"))
```

Outside of GAE, I normally use the `google-cloud-datastore` client to access Datastore models:

```
from google.cloud import datastore

...
client = datastore.Client(project_id)
query = client.query(kind='Event', order=('-date',))
for result in query.fetch(limit=100):
    print result

# every result is of class `google.cloud.datastore.entity.Entity`
```

**Question**: What if I'm only given the encoded byte string? How can I convert it back to a `google.cloud.datastore.entity.Entity` (or `dict`)?

---

### Followups:

**Update1**: 
`google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1.entity_pb2.Entity.ParseFromString()` is the closest I found so far. But not quite working yet..

```
## fetched a protobuf into `pb`
>>> pb.__class__
<class 'google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1.entity_pb2.Entity'>

>>> entity = google.cloud.datastore.helpers.entity_from_protobuf(pb)
>>> entity.__class__
<class 'google.cloud.datastore.entity.Entity'>

>>> serialized = pb.SerializeToString()     ## <-- now this is the bytestring I meant.
>>> type(serialized)
<type 'str'>

>>> google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1.entity_pb2.Entity.ParseFromString(serialized)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'ParseFromString' requires a 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.CMessage' object but received a 'str'

>>>google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1.entity_pb2.Entity().ParseFromString(serialized)
76942    ## <--??
```

**Update2**:

Actually had to do this:

```
e = google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1.entity_pb2.Entity()
e.ParseFromString(byte_str)
print e
```

And that did it..

Comment: You ahould add it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

this worked:

```
e = google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1.entity_pb2.Entity()
e.ParseFromString(byte_str)
print e
```