# Is the schema needed to deserialize protobuf bytestring?

Tags: google-app-engine, serialization, google-cloud-datastore, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to deserialize some Protobuf bytestrings, in Python, outside of GAE(AppEngine) environment. I'm wondering if I need the message schema for this use case.

Approaches I've tried so far includes `google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1.entity_pb2.Entity.ParseFromString()`:

```
>>> pb = ...  ## fetched a protobuf into `pb` using the Datastore Protobuf API

>>> pb.__class__
<class 'google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1.entity_pb2.Entity'>

>>> serialized = pb.SerializeToString()     ## <-- now `serialized` is a bytestring.
>>> type(serialized)
<type 'str'>

>>> e = google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1.entity_pb2.Entity()
>>> e.ParseFromString(serialized)   ## <-- deserialization
>>> print e
```

The deserialization above actually worked, so I'm assuming I don't need a to know the message schema. --Correct me if I'm wrong.

However, I tried this on a different bytestring, it didn't work. But it worked with `google.appengine.ext.db.model_from_protobuf(bytestring2)` in GAE environment though.

Thoughts?? Thanks

### Other notes

Somewhat [relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433260/db-model-from-protobuf-equivalents-outside-of-appengine).